# Transform a table from rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got an ordered Microsoft Server table of the following form:

```
    Name   Product
  ------------------
1 | Mayer  Product_1
2 | Mayer  Product_1
3 | Mayer  Product_2
```

And I would like to gain the following result:

```
    Name   Purchase_1 Purchase_2 Purchase_3
  -----------------------------------------
1 | Mayer  Product_1  Product_1  Product_2
```

The code has to work for an arbitrary length of purchases and names, meaning I don't know these information upfront.

Comment: are Name and Product the only 2 columns in the source table?

Comment: @JamieD77 Yes, just those two. :)

Comment: then converting them to columns makes no sense because there's no defined order.

Comment: @JamieD77 The table is already ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dynamic PIVOT** is your friend :

**[LiveDEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374845)**

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   Name  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL 
  ,Product VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('Mayer','Product_1');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('Mayer','Product_1');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('Mayer','Product_2');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('Kowalsky','Product_1');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('Kowalsky','Product_2');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('Kowalsky','Product_3');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('Kowalsky','Product_4');

DECLARE @cols  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @cols_piv NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@max  INT = 0;

SELECT @max = MAX(c)
FROM (
  SELECT Name, COUNT(Product) AS c
  FROM #mytable
  GROUP BY Name) AS s;

SET @cols = STUFF(     
            (SELECT ',' +  CONCAT('[',c.n, '] AS Purchase_',c.n, ' ')
            FROM  ( SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n)AS c(n)
            WHERE c.n <= @max
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @cols_piv = STUFF(
            (SELECT ',' +  CONCAT('[',c.n, '] ')
            FROM  ( SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n)AS c(n)
            WHERE c.n <= @max
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');        

SET @query = N'SELECT Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Name, Product,
                [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Product)
                from #mytable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Product)
                for rn in (' + @cols_piv + ')
            ) p ';

-- SELECT @query; 

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
    @query;
```

It may be complicated at first but this is really simple. Normal `PIVOT` requires you to know column list in advance. This is not an option in your case so you need to generate column and use Dynamic-SQL.

How it works:

1. `@max` contains max number of columns per row
2. `@cols` contains `SELECT` column list with aliases
3. `@cols_piv` contains list of numbers `[1], [2], ... @max`
4. Concatenate it with normal `PIVOT` query
5. Execute it and enjoy your results.

**Warning:**

- I've used `sys.objects` as my number generator. You can replace it with what you want (recursive CTE/multistep CTE/tally table ...).
- If you are using SQL Server 2008 you need to replace `CONCAT` with `+`.

Comment: Thank you, lad2025! This was really fast! :) Since I'm new to SQL I don't understand much of the code you've provided. Is there a simpler way to do this? Or could you please explain to me what you're doing in the code above?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! :) Unfortunately, I can't see where I have to put the object names like [db_name].[dbo].[table_name] and [column_name]. Can you give me some pointers here? Thank you again!

Comment: @underscore_d Nope, because he wants to work for arbitrary table. So I cannot assume how many products `Mayer` have bought.