# Write result of query into a new table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I write the result of the SQL Server query, displayed in this question : [Transform a table from rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083918/transform-a-table-from-rows-to-columns), into a new table?

I tried the following, but it isn't working:

```
SELECT * INTO [dbo.table] FROM query;
```

Comment: What error do you get? and does `dbo.table` exist?

Comment: try select * from [dbo.table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multipart name **schema_name.table_name**:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[new_table_name] 
FROM query;
```

For your case you need to use:

```
SET @query = N'SELECT Name, ' + @cols + ' 
            INTO [dbo].[new_table_name]
            from 
            (
                select Name, Product,
                [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Product)
                from #mytable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Product)
                for rn in (' + @cols_piv + ')
            ) p ';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @query;

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[new_table_name];
```

Keep in mind that if table exists you need first to `DROP` it:

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[new_table_name];
```

The problem with your approach is that **dynamic PIVOT** can return variable length columns. So the next call will be different and you need to recreate table every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the data to an existing table, you will need to use...

```
Insert Into dbo.Table (column1, column2) 
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM query
```

However, if youre looking to use a Temp Table, you will need...

```
SELECT * INTO #table FROM query;
```

There's a [comprehensive article here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/) on using Temp Tables etc

Comment: No he can't use temp table as you proposed `INTO #temp` because he is using Dynamic-SQL. The table will be in new context and cease to exists when Dynamic-SQL is finished.

Comment: @lad2025, Now I am seeing the other question - I have updated this question to remove the *here* part and replace it with the question title.